# Method dispatchNow works but dispatch method go to failed jobs

Tags: laravel

My problem is very simple but I can't understand what's wrong.

Below is my method "menusEdition" from my controller :

```
public function menusEdition(Request $request){
    $menus = Menu::where('day',$request->day)->get();

    foreach($menus as $menu){
        $job = new MenusEdition($menu);
        $this->dispatchNow($job);
    }
    return back();
}
```

And this is my Job "MenusEdition" :

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Http\Controllers\MenusController;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MenusEdition implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($menu)
    {
        $this->menu = $menu;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MenusController $menusController)
    {
        $menu = $this->menu;
        $menusController->templateEdition($menu->id);
        return;
    }
```

The templateEdition method is in my MenusController.

When I use the dispatchNow method the jobs are done but when I use the dispatch method the jobs fail :

[image: Failed job exception]

I know this is a very simple problem but after spending most of my day looking for tutorials and other threads I still can't get it right.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variable. Add this code in your MenusEdition class right before construct method.

`protected $menu;`

Like in [this example.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#class-structure)

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your help. This worked. However,when I try to use the convert API, I get this error :

ConvertApi\Error\Client: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in C:\laragon\www\webapp_adminLTE\vendor\convertapi\convertapi-php\lib\ConvertApi\Client.php:119

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: @LouisCharles welcome. ) For your new question it's better to create new post, because it's very different topic.